# Unwanted Reverb effect developing program on Mac OS X Sierra with coreaudio

Tags: macos, core-audio, macos-sierra

I've made a program which uses coreaudio to output sound. It worked perfect before Mac OS X Sierra. Now on this version, the program has an unwanted reverb effect that I don't know where it comes from.

The curious point here is that, if I run the program inside the app bundle /Applications/program.app/Contents. the reverb effect can be heard, but if I run the program from the build path, there's no reverb effect.
I think it happens because the app bundle path has the typical Info.plist file, and on the build path there's no plist file....